# How to install apt-get packages on Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-function-app

Running a python Azure function on Linux consumption plan. I have been able to successfully deploy the function to Azure using VS Code. All the packacges in requirements.txt are getting installed without a problem. But now i need to install tesseract which only can be installed through apt-get

Comment: Can you try using custom containers ?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=bash%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-csharp

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: +1 Also interested in this. Would like to run a list of bash commands in the container that `func azure functionapp publish` uses.

Answer (score -1):

You can use tasks.json in the Azure function project which allows you to configure tasks which would run. There is even a breakdown on an operating system level e.g. windows should run specific commands and Linux should run differently.