# Running sudo command on a Azure function app using consumption plan

Tags: python, azure-functions, zbar

I am trying to deploy an azure function written using python to an azure function app. The function is using pyzbar library. The pyzbar library documentation says that in a Linux environment, the below command needs to be executed so that the pyzbar can work.

```
sudo apt-get install libzbar0
```

How can I execute this command on the consumption plan. Please note that I can get this to work if I deploy the function with a container approach using a premium or a dedicated plan. But I want to get this to work using the consumption plan.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61846829/how-to-install-apt-get-packages-on-azure-function

Comment: I have a similar problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

- I have a work around where every time you trigger your function it will run a script that will install the required packages using the command prompt.
- This can be achieved using subprocess module

code :

```
subprocess.run(["apt-get"," install"," libzbar0"])
```

for Example in the following code I am installing pandas using pip and returning it's version.

[image]

- But this will increase your execution time as even if you have added the packages it will continue to execute the installation commands every time you trigger the function.

Comment: I tried this approach but it seems to be not working. Although the pip command works, I guess the apt-get command is not working.

Comment: well I rerun the code again apparently the apt-get will work in the same code but only in function-premium not consumption plan